# How to differentiate between no http application hitting ML and ML not responding?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Say I don't see any API response in 45 secs.
I want to check whether there was actually no hit to MarkLogic or MarkLogic was not able to complete any request during this time.
Not being able to send response to http request could be due to actual MarkLogic database getting offline or it could be also due to some lagging operations as well.
So what lagging messages should suffice ?
Can `Warning: Canary thread` lookup be enough?
I wet through this manual - https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/437/0/warning-messages-for-lagging-operations.
Will I have to look for multiple lagging warnings ? That would create more complexity.
If I could look for just one or two type of warnings and that should suffice.

Comment: Did you check the Access log for the port (which records the request and HTTP status code of the response)?  Also, if the request goes to the REST API, the restapi trace event (which logs to the request log in MarkLogic 10) or URL Rewrite trace event http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/appserver-control#id_25611 might provide more diagnostic information.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out a way to answer the question about whether MarkLogic is up and responding when someone else is trying to figure out why their app isn't working and throws it over the fence to say "is MarkLogic responding to our calls?" Is there a normal SLA for response times of these calls? Do you currently experience lagging operations or MarkLogic going offline?

Comment: @MadsHansen Yes, no response for any calls till or above 30 secs. Yes we do experience lagging operations. few calls taking more time is fine but during lagging operations no calls get response. I'm focussed on this one. When no calls gets response for 30 secs we consider that a downtime but ML says I'm up and running.

Comment: The lagging operation fix will be upgrading our server but at present we can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for things that indicate lagging operations, then I would recommend searching for the following as possible signs of trouble that could result in delays:

- `Warning: Canary thread`

  - https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/437/0/warning-messages-for-lagging-operations
- `Memory low`

  - https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/527
- `Slow`

  - https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/508/0/understanding-slow-infrastructure-notifications
  - https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/642
- `Hung`

  - https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/hung-messages-in-the-errorlog
- `Stopping XDQPServerConnection`

  - https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/459/0/xml-data-query-protocol-xdqp
- `XDMP-CLOCKSKEW`

  - https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/24/15/system-clock-synchronization-and-xdmp-clockskew